Clion monitor esp32 not show all logs
I have a Clion in version form 2024.1 and ESP_IDF is 5.1.2v . I configured some porject for esp32c3 and CMake application as build, flash works fine for me, except monitor. If I run these I see as it works but lose much many lines logs (you can see it in attachment screen shots)
If I run esp tool monitor form terminal
idf.py monitor 

all works fine. I must add also that I have previous oldes version Clion some form 2022 and ESP_IDF 4.3.2v then monitor works good.


